# Special character checking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
var string = "asdasASFASDŞGFSD123435489()/%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&123435";
```

I want this string to have a space after any group of ampersands. So in this example, I want the output:

```
"asdasASFASDŞGFSD123435489()/%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 123435";
```

How can I accomplish this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, mine is cooler ;)

```
 var string = "asdasASFASDŞGFSD123435489()/%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&123435";
 alert(string.replace(/&+/g, "$& "))
```

Comment: Thanks!,

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&123435 I want to separe them since with & they have some special meaning then they don't appear on the web page.

Comment: in the replacement string, does mere `$` stand for the whole matched string?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the job of regular expressions. For example you could do something like this (not tested, just to get the idea):

```
string.replace("(&+)", "$1 ");
```